# How to get cell value from DataGridView in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a problem, how can i get value from cell of datagridview

```
----------------------------------
id     | p/w       | post       |
----------------------------------
1      |   1234    | A          |
----------------------------------
2      | 4567      | S          |
----------------------------------
3      | 6789      | A          |
----------------------------------
```

I want to get 3 into the textbox,how to do that? Can anyone give some example coding?
than you~

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The line would be as shown below:

```
Dim x As Integer    
x = dgvName.Rows(yourRowIndex).Cells(yourColumnIndex).Value
```

Comment: currently in my datagridview have 3 rows  
  i write the code like this:  

  Dim numberOfRow As Integer  
  Dim x As Integer  

  numberOfRow=Datagridview1.Rows.Count -1  
  x = Datagridview1.Rows(numberOfRow).Cells(0).Value  

  the result of numberOfRow is 3  
  but the result of x not 3

Comment: @JosephKim From the appeareance of your data, the numberOfRow value should want to use is two.  This is because DataGridViewRows have a zero-based index.  i.e. "1" is the value of ".Row(0).Cell(0)", "2" is the value of ".Row(1).Cell(0)", and so on

Comment: @JosephKim .. isn't that NumberOfRow=Datagridview1.Rows.Count ?

Comment: @JosephKim Also, you should not have your column headers inserted into the first row on your table.  Set the DataGridViewColumn.HeaderText to the desired text if you currently have them inserted into the table itself. [headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.headertext(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

It is working for me

```
MsgBox(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In you want to know the data from de selected row, you can try this snippet code:

```
DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells(1).Value
```

Answer (score 3):

This helped me get close to what I needed and I will throw this out there for anyone else who needs it.

If you are looking for the value in the first cell in the selected column, you can try this.  (I chose the first column, since you are asking for it to return "3", but you can change the number after Cells to get whichever column you need.  Remember it is zero-based.)

This will copy the result to the clipboard:
`Clipboard.SetDataObject(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)`

Answer (score 3):

To get the value of cell, use the following syntax,

```
datagridviewName(columnFirst, rowSecond).value
```

But the intellisense and MSDN documentation is wrongly saying `rowFirst, colSecond` approach...