# Get name of file stored in SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, byte, filenames

I am modifying old application and I have to add functionality to allow user view a file from SQL. File needs to be saved in temporary folder and deleted after closing application. I've managed to do all above, but I have to get filename of downloaded file (now Im using a string variable filename = "TemporaryDoc").
How can I get a filename from a data that is stored in datagridview.Rows(0).Items(0) ?

Comment: You are trying to get the values of DataGrid rows ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721984/vb-net-how-to-get-cell-value-from-datagridview

Comment: Hope the below will help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721984/vb-net-how-to-get-cell-value-from-datagridview