# Add datagrid columns to database?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to add a users selected row to the database

I want the CarID, CarBrand, And CarModel to enter

When the user selected that row they click a button to add it to the database 
I seem to be getting errors and I'm not sure why

Here is my code

```
    Private Sub Btn_addtorental_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_addtorental.Click
    If datcarsearchresults.SelectedRows.Count = 1 Then
        Dim SelectedCarID As Integer = datcarsearchresults.SelectedRows(0).Tag
        Dim SelectedCarBrand As String = datcarsearchresults.SelectedColumns(1)
        Dim SelectedCarModel As String = datcarsearchresults.SelectedColumns(2)
        PublicCarID = SelectedCarID
        If DbConnect() Then
            Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand
            With SQLCmd
                .Connection = cn
                .CommandText = "Insert into Tbl_Rental (CarID,CarBrand,CarModel)  " & "Values (@CarID,@CarBrand,@CarModel)"
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarID", SelectedCarID)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarBrand", SelectedCarBrand)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarModel", SelectedCarModel)

                .ExecuteNonQuery()
```

It says it cannot be converted to string??

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is it erroring? I'm guessing when you try to get the value from the column.  The SelectedColumns(1) doesn't bring back a string but brings back a DataGridViewColumnCollection.  Take a look at this link with more answers. [vb.net how to get cell value from datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721984/vb-net-how-to-get-cell-value-from-datagridview).